# Rewrite every request to one file with url as parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am coding a small CMS in PHP and need to redirect all requests to that file (called `cms.php` in my case). For example

```
/~ps0ke/ -> /~ps0ke/cms.php?path=index.html
/~ps0ke/projects/cms.html -> /~ps0ke/cms.php?path=projects/cms.html
```

and so on. There is also a `lang` paramter that is set if `en/` is preceding the directory. This should not be of importance because my problem existed before I added multi-lingual support. Right now I am using Apache and the following `.htaccess` to achieve the rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~ps0ke/

# Serve index.html via cms.php when base dir or index.html is requested. Also
# set the language.
RewriteRule ^((en)/)?(index.html)?$ cms.php?lang=$2&path=index.html [NC,L]

# Serve everything else via cms.php. Also set the language.
# Serving from the page subdirectory is due to a problem with all-wildcard
# RewriteRule. This might be fixed.
RewriteRule ^((en)/)?page/(.*)$ cms.php?lang=$2&path=$3 [NC,L,B]
```

you may notice that there is an additional `page/` in between the `RewriteBase` and the actual path. I am doing this because simply matching for

```
RewriteRule ^((en)/)?(.*)$ cms.php?lang=$2path=$3 [NC,L,B]
```

simply does not work. I don't understand why. When I use the rule as above outputting `$_GET` results in

```
Array
(
    [lang] => 
    [path] => cms.php
)
```

Regardless of the actual GET path, the `path` GET-Variable is always set to the script's name. And I just don't understand why.

The reason I don't want to have the `page/` prefix included is that it maintains backwards compatibility. The CMS is specialized in serving a normal file structure and builds its navigation etc. just from the file system. Therefor it would be nice to have the actual real file structure represented in the GET path. Therefore, even if someone removes the CMS again, the links would still work.

Just easier reference I put in the Apache manual entries for the options used:

> **NC|nocase**
>
> Use of the [NC] flag causes the RewriteRule to be matched in a
>   case-insensitive manner. That is, it doesn't care whether letters
>   appear as upper-case or lower-case in the matched URI.
>
> **B (escape backreferences)**
>
> The [B] flag instructs RewriteRule to escape non-alphanumeric
>   characters before applying the transformation.
>
> **L|last**
>
> The [L] flag causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set. In
>   most contexts, this means that if the rule matches, no further rules
>   will be processed. This corresponds to the last command in Perl, or
>   the break command in C. Use this flag to indicate that the current
>   rule should be applied immediately without considering further rules.

Any help (a fix or an explanation) is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are getting into this problem because your rules are executing twice. You can stop it by avoiding all resources (js, image, css etc) to rewrite and also not letting it run second time.

Have your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~ps0ke/

# avoid any rules for resources and 2nd time:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js)$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Serve index.html via cms.php when base dir or index.html is requested. Also
# set the language.
RewriteRule ^((en)/)?(index.html)?$ cms.php?lang=$2&path=index.html [NC,L,QSA]

# Serve everything else via cms.php. Also set the language.
# Serving from the page subdirectory is due to a problem with all-wildcard
# RewriteRule. This might be fixed.
RewriteRule ^((en)/)?(.*)$ cmas.php?lang=$2path=$3 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you this does mostly what I need. I have two additional requests: 1st: Is there a way to make it possible to serve any type of files without explicitly mentioning its extension in the .htaccess? When I comment out that specific line everything works as expected but image serving. My script is capable of serving binary data, so it would not be needed explicitly.

Comment: The 2nd thing is: somehow I am getting redirects of some sort when requesting URLs that point to a directory (even though index.html is served silently instead). My links always point to clean URLs `/~ps0ke/tests/image/` but using Chrome or Firefox I land on pages like `/~ps0ke/tests/image/?lang=&path=tests%2fimage`. I really don't have any idea where this might come from, using `curl --head` does not show any redirect header. If you have an idea how to solve this, it would be awesome. I'd like to hide the ugly implementation completely from the end user.

Comment: ok check my edit now directory rewriting problem will be resolved. Test in a new browser. Also I suggest not adding new requirements from comments.

Comment: Thanks again for your time. I will edit my question to include all additional requests in the end (if this is the way to go? I am relatively new to StackOverflow). Unfortunately on the your edit solved one issue but introduced another. GET parameters are now not displayed anymore. Everything works fine so far, but if a directory does not have a `index.html` in it, Apache serves its own `+Indexes` directory index.

Comment: Turning `Indexes` off just gives me a 403. I would not like to rewrite a directory URL and append an `index.html` so much as this is logic better be handled by the PHP script. Any suggestions? :)

Comment: Hmm rather than changing requirements and adding new ones it is better to create a new question with these requirements and mark this on as accepted.